# calculate only selected input text with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to calculate the sum from multiple selected input text form, that are selected with  checkbox like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="satelitep">
<input type="checkbox" value="sateliteon" name="satelite">
```

How can i do this whit JavaScript or jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you summing? Also, what have you tried already (post code)?

Answer (score 1):

You can select them and get the size:

```
var score = $("input:checkbox[checked=true]").size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var sum = 0;

$("input:checkbox [name='satelite']:checked").each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).prev().val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job.

```
var counter = 0;
$('input:checked').prev().each(function(index){
     counter += parseFloat(this.val());
});
```

It is untested, but should show the basic idea.  It requires jQuery.

This finds all `checked` input fields, finds the fields immediately preceding them, then loops over each of them, adding their value to a counter.

Hope this helps